# Get IP address on BlackBerry of a device from which there is incoming socket connection to me

Tags: sockets, blackberry, ip

Like there are methods in Core Java and Android, is there any means to know the IP address of the device or desktop that sends me a socket connection, on BlackBerry?

This apart from sending the IP address in XML tags, as there is a need to have an API that does so...

I need to know methods in BlackBerry, matching getSocketAddress() which gives full detail, or getINetAddress() which only gives the IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `javax.microedition.io.SocketConnection` class has a `getAddress()` method to return the address of the remote party on a socket connection.